# my code cannot run because of this a[j]=sc.nextInt();

Tags: java, arrays, methods

class test10{

```
    static double displaySalesObject(String id , double amount) {
    return amount;
    }
    
     public static void main (String[] args) {

        sales s1 = new sales ();
        sales s2 = new sales ();
        
        System.out.print(s1.getsalesid() + "," + s1.getamount());
        System.out.print(s2.getsalesid() + "," + s2.getamount());
        s1.determineDiscount();
        s2.determineDiscount();
    //}

    //public static void main(String args[]) {
//  public void displaySalesArray(){        
    //Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a=new int[6];
    System.out.println("Please enter elements...");
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    //a[j]=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Array elements are : ");
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

}

** i try to past array using method . is it a right way to use it? and also have error at a[j]=sc.nextInt(); **

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for?

```
public class Test {

    static double displaySalesObject(String id, double amount) {
        return amount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sales s1 = new sales();
        sales s2 = new sales();

        System.out.print(s1.getSalesid() + "," + s1.getAmount());
        System.out.print(s2.getSalesid() + "," + s2.getSalesid());
        s1.determineDiscount();
        s2.determineDiscount();
        System.out.println("Please enter elements...");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[6];
        passArrayToTheMethod(sc, a);
    }

    private static void passArrayToTheMethod(Scanner sc, int[] a) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            a[j] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Array elements are : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
```